# Where is the return value of a function stored in memory if I don't save it in a variable?

Tags: delphi

Where is the return value of a function stored in memory if I don't save it in a variable and how long does it stay there? Does it get overwritten by another function or execution immediately after I have used the return value? How do I manually forcably overwrite that memory if it stays there for a while?

Please consider the following when RunProgram is called...

```
function GetAValue : Integer;
begin
  Result := {some integer value based on other conditions};
end;

procedure RunProgram;
begin
  If GetAValue = 362411 then
    ShowMessage('Found');
end;
```

So when GetAValue is called to make the above "If statement" comparison then...

- May I assume that the result of it is stored in memory to be able to
  compare with?
- May I assume that that memory will be overwritten/discarded shortly
  as it will not be needed anymore?
- How do I make sure it is discarded immediately if I wanted it to be?
- Will anybody debugging the above program be able to read that memory
  when the comparison is done and as such be able to see what the value
  is which GetAValue returned at that stage?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembly_Procedures_and_Functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably depends on the optimisation settings. An integer value is returned in EAX. With optimisation enabled I'd expect the compiler to perform the comparison directly using the value returned in EAX. With optimisation disabled then the compiler might to unpack to a temporary local on the stack. You can check the code that the compiler emits.

Exactly when the register and/or stack value are overwritten depends on the code around this fragment.

However, the value is clear to see by anyone debugging. It's in the EAX register. The fact that it isn't stored in a named Delphi variable is beside the point. Since the code uses the value, it can be seen by a debugger. There's nothing at all that you can do to hide anything once your program is being debugged.

For completeness, here are the answers to your bullet point list of questions:

> May I assume that the result of it is stored in memory to be able to compare with?

No. The value can be stored in a register.

> May I assume that that memory will be overwritten/discarded shortly as it will not be needed anymore?

No. The compiler won't write out code to explicitly overwrite memory that is no longer used. Stale values may persist.

> How do I make sure it is discarded immediately if I wanted it to be?

Find out where it is stored, and overwrite that location. As discussed though, this won't help.

> Will anybody debugging the above program be able to read that memory when the comparison is done and as such be able to see what the value is which GetAValue returned at that stage?

Yes. A debugger can see everything.